# The provided URI scheme 'net.tcp' is invalid; expected 'http'

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm a newbie at WCF.  I'm trying to edit existing code to use a net.tcp binding instead of a http binding.  I have done this easily in test projects using the config files, but for various reasons, in the real project it is done programatically.

I made the necessary changes, and the service host seems to start correctly:

```
 Uri baseAdress= new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:7005/MyService/");
 host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyServiceImpl), baseAdress);

 host.AddServiceEndpoint(
              typeof(MyService),
              new NetTcpBinding(),
              "");

 ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior;
 metadataBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

 if (metadataBehavior == null)
 {
      metadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
      host.Description.Behaviors.Add(metadataBehavior);
 }

 BindingElement bindingElement = new TcpTransportBindingElement();
 CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(bindingElement);
 host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), binding, "mex");

 host.Open();
```

So far so good.  I edited the connection string client side:

```
 string serverUri = string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/MyService", serverName, port);
 MyService server = new MyServiceClient("MYS", serverUri);
```

But when i try to call functions from my service, i get this error:

> The provided URI scheme 'net.tcp' is invalid; expected 'http'

Not quite sure what i am missing...  Any hints?

Comment: Have you updated your client after you switched to net.tcp?

Comment: Thank you, yes i took another look at the client config file and noticed a missing endpoint.  I still get an error regarding the Channel.  I'll try to work it out else i will post an update